# Configure static IP with port number which will point to multiple projects on different ports

Tags: linux, virtualhost

I am developing a project in LAM* and using the Symfony framework.

I have one static IP like **99.99.99.99:8000** which points on my Linux server machine.
This static IP already has port number of 8000.
This Linux server machine has multiple project hosted on it and we access each project in LAN with different port number like abc:81, pqr:82, xyz:83.

Is is possible to access each project on same Linux machine by this static IP?
If yes then please let me know how to configure and call each project using this IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a proxy service (nginx, apache etc.) on your server and redirect requests to backends using domain names.

s1.domain.com:8000 -> localhost:81

s2.domain.com:8000 -> localhost:82

...

You have to create virtual hosts ("NamedVirtualHost"s for apache or "server" definitions for nginx) in your proxy service configuration and add related proxy pass definitions to these virtualhosts.